# data.table SELECT GROUP BY column index in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm iterating through a the columns in a dataframe (it also is a data table later in my code). In SQL, the equivalent of what I want to do for each variable looks like:

```
SELECT COUNT(VAR) FROM df GROUP BY MonthYear
```

I'm having some trouble doing thing in R, though. The file I have is structured poorly, so I have some sort of a `dplyr`+ `data.table` workaround I'm trying to get functional.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(MonthYear = c("JAN15", "JAN15", "FEB15", "MAR15", "MAR15"), V1 = c(1,1,0,0,0), V2 = c(0,1,1,1,0), V3 = c(0,0,0,1,1), V4 = c(0,1,1,1,1))

for(colNum in 2:length(names(df))){
    colName <- names(df)[colNum]
    filtered <- select(df, c(1, colNum))
    filtered_dt <- data.table(filtered, key = "MonthYear")
    trimmed <- filtered_dt[, count = sum(colName), by = key(filtered_dt)]
}
```

This results in and error:

> Error in sum(column) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument

For `V1`, I know the `trimmed` assignment should look like:

```
trimmed <- filtered_dt[, count = sum(V1), by = key(filtered_dt)]
```

I just don't know how to get the character value of `"V1"` to fit that syntax.

Comment: You have a typo. Wrap the `count = sum(colName)` in `.()`. This is in the FAQ: https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#unused-arguments-mysum-sumv Not sure if that's your only problem.

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question, though. I get the same error. How can I make the `character` `"V1"` value work in that `trimmed` line?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to suggest that it answered your question.

Comment: Use `get(colName)`.

Comment: you don't need `length(names(df))`; `length(df)` will do just fine.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Why doesn't `df[ , lapply(.SD, sum), by = MonthYear]` suffice? Splitting this operation into many different tables seems inadvisable.

Comment: @Arun 's answer works. You can also use `trimmed <- filtered_dt[, count := sum(eval(parse(text = colName))), by = key(filtered_dt)]` . You also have a `=` where a `:=` should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question is confusing, you use SQL `count(var)` while in the code, and provided example it looks like you want to use `sum(var)`. Using `count(var)` will counts all non-NULL elements, including duplicates.
Assuming you want to `sum` your variables by month then solution in Michael comment is efficient and clean answer:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(MonthYear = c("JAN15", "JAN15", "FEB15", "MAR15", "MAR15"), V1 = c(1,1,0,0,0), V2 = c(0,1,1,1,0), V3 = c(0,0,0,1,1), V4 = c(0,1,1,1,1))
setDT(df)
df[ , lapply(.SD, sum), by = MonthYear]
#   MonthYear V1 V2 V3 V4
#1:     JAN15  2  1  0  1
#2:     FEB15  0  1  0  1
#3:     MAR15  0  1  2  2
```

In case if your example data are not well fitting your problem and you really want SQL's `count(var)` then just use `df[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(!is.na(x))), by = MonthYear]`, this will count non-NA elements by group.